# Setting focus to an embedded Flash movie/HTML embed element using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, firefox, google-chrome

Is there a way to set focus to the embed HTML element using JavaScript? Test case: embedded YouTube videos on a page.

I have no control over the embedded Flash element. So, is there a way to set focus on it by using only JavaScript?

I read somewhere that calling the element.focus() method works only in IE. I need a browser-independent way that works in Chrome/Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This only works in Internet Explorer.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15586.html

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do this too, and ended up to a nice solution using jquery:

var gotoflash=jQuery("#flash_file").offset().top;jQuery("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: gotoflash}, 1000);

where: <*div id="flash_file"> flash object code here <*/div>

Comment: I tried this. But as far as I can comprehend, this is meant to scroll the page to the flash object. I actually want to set focus to the element.

So that, for eg., in YouTube, after setting focus to the element, I can use the keyboard shortcuts like "space" for playing/pausing the video

Comment: hm..i understood... try this,it works: <body onload="document.OBJECTID.focus();"> ,where OBJECTID is: <object ... id="OBJECTID" name="OBJECTID"><embed .... id="OBJECTID" name="OBJECTID">...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by adding flash content dynamically, for example with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't confirmed this, but you could try:

```
function thisMovie(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
    } else {
         return document[movieName];
    }
}

    // Call from within another function:
    thisMovie("FlashObjectID").focus();
    thisMovie("FlashObjectID").showFlash(); 
    // showFlash() is an AS3 ExternalInterface call from JS to .swf which establishes the TextInput.setFocus(); method
```

source: http://www.htmlforums.com/archive/index.php/t-64150.html